# How can I get x number of records where json column does not overlaps between selected rows in MySQL 8?

Tags: mysql

I have a table of possible ids combinations where ids per each row is unique:

```
| id | numbers              |
|----|----------------------|
|  1 | [10, 23, 16, 34, 35] |
|  2 | [10, 27, 14, 41, 33] |
|  3 | [10, 24, 18, 34, 37] |
|  4 | [10, 27, 17, 39, 30] |
|  5 | [10, 26, 15, 34, 38] |
|  6 | [10, 20, 16, 39, 29] |
|  7 | [10, 27, 16, 28, 37] |
|  8 |  [1, 26, 16, 41, 28] |
|  9 |  [7, 24, 13, 31, 36] |
| 10 | [10, 23, 17, 33, 37] |
| 11 |  [8, 22, 14, 30, 35] |
| 12 |  [2, 25, 18, 29, 40] |
| 13 |  [3, 27, 15, 42, 34] |
| 14 |    [5, 6, 9, 53, 84] |
| 15 | [12, 66, 59, 91, 11] |

.... ~10k more rows
```

```
CREATE TABLE `ids_combinations` (
  `id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `numbers` json NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

And I need to select exactly 7 random records where all of rows ids does not overlap like below:

```
| id | numbers              |
|----|----------------------|
|  8 |  [1, 26, 16, 41, 28] |
|  9 |  [7, 24, 13, 31, 36] |
| 10 | [10, 23, 17, 33, 37] |
| 11 |  [8, 22, 14, 30, 35] |
| 12 |  [2, 25, 18, 29, 40] |
| 13 |  [3, 27, 15, 42, 34] |
| 14 |    [5, 6, 9, 53, 84] |
```

So far I have tried to select using json function `json_table()` but with no luck yet :/

Comment: Have a look at [`JSON_OVERLAPS()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-overlaps)

Comment: Do show what you tried